# SQL Server error when creating Geography data from a Multipolygon Geometry

Tags: postgis, sql-server, geography-data-type, pgadmin-4, typecast

So, in SQL server, I have a table called `Municipios`, which contains a column with 2463 entries of geometry type, with their SRID set to 4326.

I'm running the following Query to try to convert them to geography type:

```
SELECT TOP 1 mun.nom_mun, geography::STGeomFromText(geom.STAsText(),4326) AS geog
FROM [dbo].[Municipios] AS mun
```

I also tried the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 mun.nom_mun, geography::STGeomFromText(geom.MakeValid().STAsText(),4326) AS geog
FROM [dbo].[Municipios] AS mun
```

The problem with both is that the generated geography is definitely wrong, here are the original geometry and the resulting geography of the first entry in `Municipios`:

Geometry:

[image]

Geography:

[image]

I also, tried getting the string of the geometry and using that to build the geography, using:

```
SELECT mun.nom_mun, geom.MakeValid().STAsText() AS geog
FROM [dbo].[Municipios] AS mun
```

to obtain the Multipolygon string and:

```
SELECT TOP 1 mun.nom_mun, geography::STGeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((...)))',4326) AS geog
FROM [dbo].[Municipios] AS mun
```

to generate the geography (I'd put the whole MULTIPOLYGON (((...))) here, but it's extremely long).

But, i still get the same wrong result.

I tried to cheat the system by using the Multipolygon string in Postgis (pgAdmin) and then move the generated geography back to SQL server. Inside pgAdmin, the resulting geography was correct:

[image]

But when i moved it back to SQL server, it was the same wrong geography.

Ideally, I'm looking for a way to do this conversion inside SQL server, if not, find a way to do it in postGis and move it back to SQL server without it becoming the same wrong projection, if none of those are options, well, any other way is good enough.

UPDATE: I also tried using Gdal/ogr2ogr with the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial -lco GEOM_TYPE=geography -lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt "MSSQL:server=tcp:XXXX;database=XXXX;uid=XXXX;pwd=XXXX" "C:\mun\mun.shp" -a_srs "EPSG:4326"
```

And obtained the same, wrong result. I feel like I'm really out of options.

Comment: About the large WKT, usually it is possible  and better to use simple geometries for testing, something like `MULTIPOLYGON ((( 0 40, 20 30, 0 30, 0 40 )), (( 0 20, 20 20, 0 10, 0 20 )))`.

Comment: @user30184 In testing, it works. I tested a MULTIPOLYGON that was around 1/4 of the original in size and it was generated correctly, I'm starting to think that the error is due to my Multipolygon being too big, but that shouldn't be a problem, right?